# Sandbox for Marketing Cloud

Tags: sandbox

I'm looking at integrating Marketing Cloud (Corporate Edition) with SFDC community and i have couple questions:

1. While MarketingCloud pricing talks about testing environment, the SFDC Marketing Cloud - account executive tells me there are no sandbox license available. I have seen lots of references to sandbox account for marketing cloud. Can someone help me out with this?
2. What connector should i use for integrating marketing cloud with sfdc community? Will that be V5?

Answer (score 2):

1) The earlier process was to get a developer edition for Marketing Cloud from [here](https://code.exacttarget.com/developer-edition/). However, it's no longer available and the site mentions

> Thank you for your interest!
>
> Thank you for your interest in the Marketing Cloud Developer Edition.
>   Developer Edition is not available for registration at this time. To
>   learn more about the Marketing Cloud, please visit
>   http://www.salesforce.com/marketing-cloud/

I did get access to a sandbox by contacting my Salesforce rep so I suggest you do the same.

2) The question is not very clear but based on what you've mentioned, it seems you are looking for [this connector](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZkSEAU).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav: I see some references in the below links on sandbox for marketing cloud.   Agreement for ET sandbox:
https://code.exacttarget.com/resources/etmc_developer_agreement.pdf


Creating an App for Marketing Cloud – Refers to sandbox account for ET
https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/marketing-cloud-apps/using-app-center-to-create-an-app.html
Perhaps, they have discontinued or have discriminatory policy for providing sandbox account.