# How can I get free or trial ExactTarget instance

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, saml

How can I get free or trial ExactTarget instance. I need to do ExactTarget SAML2.0 Single Sign-On connector development, integration and testing. Is there any step by step documentation available so that I can work on ExactTarget SAML2.0 Single Sign-On ?

Comment: See this: [Get marketing cloud instance](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108802/sandbox-for-marketing-cloud/108825#108825)

Answer (score 3):

Developer Editions of Marketing Cloud [are no longer available](https://code.exacttarget.com/developer-edition/). However, I was told by the team that provided the Developer Edition program that developer account are still available by request. You should be able to contact your Account Representative to request one. If you still have issues, connect with me on [LinkedIn](http://linkedin.com/in/eliot) and I can setup an introduction with the right person to get you one.

Details on implementing SAML SSO in Marketing Cloud [are documented here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/single_sign_on_authentication_via_saml_20/).

Comment: Hi Eliot, I am in need of one of those developer accounts. What is the process to get one?

Comment: Marketing Cloud developer accounts are now only available to registered Partners. If you are a Salesforce Partner, then you can request a free Marketing Cloud developer account by creating a case on the Partner Portal.

Comment: Hi @Eliot Harper, we have our app listed in AppExchange. Am I eligible to request a marketing cloud developer account?

Answer (score 0):

You can hopefully encourage Saelesforce to come through for everyone by voting for this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1yFAAQ

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please don't use sign-offs in your answers (see [answer]) - every post you make already includes your user card.