# Marketing Cloud - How to get queue size of triggered-sends via APIs

Tags: marketing-cloud, queue, size

We have multiple BUs configured in Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) and each BU has multiple triggered-sends configured. Now, we are trying to find out how to get queue size for each triggered-send in a specific BU.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get free or trial ExactTarget instance](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122522/how-can-i-get-free-or-trial-exacttarget-instance)

Answer (score 2):

There's no queue size for [Triggered Sends](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/) in SFMC.

Emails will queue and send (first-in, first-out) indefinitely as long as the trigger is not paused.

Comment: Thanks Adam. In my case, due to multiple issues, queue size is building up to 1000s of email.....perhaps the right question would be:
How do I get notified if queue size exceeds, say 1000....in other words some sort of queue size monitoring and alerting.

Comment: It shouldn't be building up unless there's a problem with an email or the payload you're sending for personalization.  SFMC Support can enable trigger monitoring, but I've found it not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[TriggeredSendSummary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/triggeredsendsummary.html) will give you details on queue size. You can query the details via SOAP Retrieve

When using the new Transactional Messaging API, you can get the details on the queue size by REST API, [Transactional Messaging: Email - Get Queue Metrics for a Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getQueueMetricsForDefinition.html)

A few examples on why a queue may continue to grow and not deliver as quickly:

1. You are approaching the 2 million per hour limit set by Salesforce Marketing Cloud (This 2 million per hour is shared by Journey Builder & Transactional Emails)
2. Some other issue in your Salesforce Marketing Cloud instance